# RedirectToAction is Taking Too much Time in Production?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I am Trying to redirect from one Controller Action to other controller Index Method.the redirection itself taking 20sec. how can i reduce the time its consuming? Actually it is a direct call it should not consume that much of time?
Is there any other way to Redirect?
here is my code

```
    public ActionResult LaunchSeletedService(int serviceId)
    {
        //some fuctionality

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {

            return new JavaScriptResult() { Script = "document.location.replace('" + Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = Area }) + "');" };
            //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = Area });
        }
        else
        {

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = Area });

        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: This is the correct way to redirect. Are you sure it is this action that is taking the time? Check in your browser Developer section under the "network Tab (In chrome)" to see how long this call is taking - Note, it could be the page that you are being redirected to, and not the call to get the redirect

Comment: I am adding the screenshot So that u can come to know that it really taking to long time to call.?

Comment: Is it the processing of the property Area that is slow or something that happens inside Index/Home? You should be able to work it out by running in the debugger. Might be something like a database connection or web service call that is slower from the production server than it is from your development environment.

Comment: There is no web service call or database connection need. i had kept the logs also.before calling the HomeController action i kept the log and After the Action method is invoked i kept the log then there i clearly see that it taking 20 sec.

Comment: It could be several things. 1) The action performing paging in memory, rather than at the database level. 2) Action filters executing on HomeController. 3)  Some incorrect logic in the view that is looping over some content, but not ending when it should be.

Comment: The network image shows the redirection response came in 90ms. The home/index resource is taking the time. You should inspect the home home/index action.